# Show appearance of a textfield like a datepicker javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, textfield, graphic

I want to add an image to a `textfield`. I used the following way

```
textfield.setStyle("-fx-background-image:url('/upgradeworkbench/View/Images/Search.png');\n"
                + "  -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;\n"
                + "  -fx-background-position: right center;");
```

But this way the image is added as a backgroud image.

[image]

I want the image to appear like the datpicker looks.

[image]

Is this possible in javafx. If yes, please tell me some way.

Comment: You could use the textfield delivered by controlsfx or  take a look at their code how they made it [TextField Source](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/1b5b2c1cde6a9dbdb1f68402badb438f257bf6bb/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields.java?at=default)

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. Appreciate the help. :)